# Laravel project for different users

Tags: web-deployment, laravel-5

The way we currently setup web app for new customers is this: I deploy app on subdomain1.example.net for a user. I create a newfolder1 on /var/www/newfolder1 and pull the project from git. create database1 in phpmyadmin. create new env file in newfolder1 to connect with database1 and update virtual host. When new customer comes we repeat this process manually.

Is there an easier way to do this? We also want to be able to allow users to dynamically create their own instance of the app from our website. I looked for tutorials, but couldnt find any. Thanks.

Comment: Seems you are willing to auto-deploy your apps upon user request. I have done this in the past with CodeIgniter apps, but actually, for the purpose of my app, this was overkill. So I decided to start [a new project](https://github.com/timegridio/timegrid) in Laravel that would allow *multiple users in the same website*. Maybe that approach fits your needs.